# Dask Worker not reachable from scheduler on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dask, dask-distributed

I have a dask setup on AWS as follows:

- Dask Scheduler on an EC2 Instance.
- Dask worker inside a docker container within another EC2 Instance.

Both of the EC2 instances are on the same VPC. The problem is just spawning the dask-worker on the container with just the ip of the scheduler doesn't work as, although the workers can complete the task, the scheduler can't reach the worker to fetch the result. Thus I keep getting:

```
distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 1 keys, rescheduling
```

I have now changed the `network_mode` of the worker container to `awsvpc` and added `listen-address` and `contact-address` to set to the IP address allotted to the container in the VPC.

```
dask-worker tcp://scheduler-host:scheduler:port --listen-address tcp://:1234 --contact-address tcp://$(hostname -i):1234
```

But I still keep getting the same error when trying to fetch the result of a future. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: The IP address allotted to the container is reachable (ping) from the scheduler instance.

Also, when I switch to `HOST` `network_mode` for the container, and spawn the dask worker as `dask-worker tcp://scheduler-host:scheduler:port --host $(hostname -i)`, it works. But I am not sure if it's the best method.

Comment: Where is your client? The message suggests that it is your client which is complaining, not the scheduler.

Comment: Does client ever try to reach the worker directly? Client is in another EC2 instance in the same VPC.

Comment: Yes, to gather data. It should be possible to route these via the scheduler. I can't immediately find how to do that. Better would be to allow direct connections from client to workers. Perhaps check out dask-gateway.

Comment: When I switch to HOST network_mode for the container, and spawn the dask worker as dask-worker tcp://scheduler-host:scheduler:port --host $(hostname -i), it works. But I am not sure if it's the best method.

Comment: @SukanyaDasgupta Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem and the usual suspects (traffic between ec2 instances in SG allowed, same VPC/subnet, etc.) don't seem to be the cause (that I can see, at least).